# Template format error: [/Resources/ElasticsearchDomain] resource definition is malformed

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, aws-cloudformation

Can you some one help whats is wrong here. i am getting [/Resources/ElasticsearchDomain] resource definition is malformed

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ElasticsearchDomain resource
Resources:
  ElasticsearchDomain:
  Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
  Properties:
    DomainName: "anvika"
    ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
      DedicatedMasterEnabled: "true"
      InstanceCount: "1"
      ZoneAwarenessEnabled: "false"
      InstanceType: "t2.small.elasticsearch"
    EBSOptions:
      EBSEnabled: true
      Iops: 0
      VolumeSize: 10
      VolumeType: "gp2"
    AccessPolicies:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
         AWS: "*"
        Action:
        - es:ESHttp*
        Condition:
          IpAddress:
            aws:SourceIp:
            - 192.0.2.0/24
        Resource: arn:aws:es:us-west-1:987654321098:domain/anvika/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of indentation issues.

1. You need to indent everything below `ElasticsearchDomain:`
2. Your arrays need to be indented.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ElasticsearchDomain resource
Resources:
  ElasticsearchDomain:
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      DomainName: "anvika"
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
        DedicatedMasterEnabled: "true"
        InstanceCount: "1"
        ZoneAwarenessEnabled: "false"
        InstanceType: "t2.small.elasticsearch"
      EBSOptions:
        EBSEnabled: true
        Iops: 0
        VolumeSize: 10
        VolumeType: "gp2"
      AccessPolicies:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: "*"
            Action:
              - es:ESHttp*
            Condition:
              IpAddress:
                aws:SourceIp:
                  - 192.0.2.0/24
            Resource: arn:aws:es:us-west-1:987654321098:domain/anvika/*
```